# How do I get CUPS onto an iOS device?

Tags: ios, compiler-construction, printing, cups

I figure that I could include a static library in my project. However, I cannot for the life of me compile CUPS for the armv6/armv7 architecture.

Am I on the right path? If so, how do I create a static library? If not, is there any way at all to get CUPS onto an iOS device?

Comment: Why do you need CUPS? iOS 4 has built in printing. In fact, I'm fairly certain iOS uses CUPS to do its printing.

Comment: I need CUPS on the device because it makes printing using IPP much easier.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm searching for a solution in printing through IPP as well, but I had no luck yet.

Comment: @Alexandre OS I wasn't able to get CUPS to work. I ended up sending the print job to a server and letting that take care of printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also setup some kind of gateway computer in order to [make CUPS printers available to iOS devices](http://netpatia.blogspot.com/2011/07/airprint-in-corporate-networks.html). We are using this [setup](http://netpatia.blogspot.com/2012/02/airprint-in-corporate-networks-ii.html) and now we are able to send print jobs from the iPad devices to any printer (HP, Lexmark, Oki, Brother, ...) in our office.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to compile CUPS? The best way to print would be using AirPrint which is now available for iOS 4. In case you want to access the CUPS admin console, I would recommend using a web view to access it.

Comment: I guess that's because AirPrint is only compatible with a few printers.